Disconnecting monitor triggers 'Oh no! Something has gone wrong.' page in Ubuntu 24.04
My computer is a Dell Precision 5540 laptop. I connect to the monitor via HDMI into a USB-C hub. I have ethernet, keyboard, mouse, webcam, and headset connected to the USB hub as well.
The problem does not happen every time I disconnect the monitor. I have no idea what triggers it. I've tried powering off the monitor first. If I click log out, the desktop returns, but with primitive graphics, and it is frozen for about 2 minutes, then I successfully log out and can log back in without a reboot. Needless to say, This is really annoying when I'm working, because I need to boot up all my work applications all over again.
Any ideas what's going on here?
EDIT 1
I tried switching the windowing system from X11 to Wayland. The behavior remains though. Applications runs really nicely on Wayland, but now the 'Oh no!' screen doesn't even appear, I just get logged out as soon as I disconnect the monitor and lose all my unsaved progress in my work.
EDIT 2
The crashing (desktop environment? windowing server? operating system? I have no idea what's actually rashing) also occurs nearly every time I close the lid of my laptop with the external monitor connected. How do I diagnose what process is crashing? This is the most depressing bug I've ever experienced.
